# Adding Data with Same Primary Key Data in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a table name AVUKAT and it's columns (`AVUKAT`, `HESAP`(Primary KEY), `MUSTERI`)

All `MUSTERI` has a one unique `HESAP` (int).

Simple I have a page like this.

[image]

First dropdown is selected MUSTERI, second is AVUKAT

And i automaticly calculating HESAP (`int` and `Primary KEY`) with this code. (On the background.)

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServerCstr"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        myConnection.Open();
        string hesapNo = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;

        string query = "select A.HESAP_NO from YAZ..MARDATA.S_TEKLIF A where A.MUS_K_ISIM = '" + hesapNo + "'";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);


        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue != "0" && DropDownList2.SelectedValue != "0")
        {
            Add.Enabled = true;
            Label1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Add.Enabled = false;

        }
        Label1.Visible = false;
        myConnection.Close();
    }
```

I just calculating `HESAP` with this code.

And my `ADD` button click function is;

```
protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        try
        {
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServerCstr"].ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            myConnection.Open();


            string hesap = Label1.Text;
            string musteriadi = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
            string avukat = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AVUKAT VALUES (@MUSTERI, @AVUKAT, @HESAP)", myConnection);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HESAP", hesap);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MUSTERI", musteriadi);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AVUKAT", avukat);
            cmd.Connection = myConnection;



            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
            myConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { 
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), " ", "alert('Bu Müşteri Zaten Mevcut!')", true);

        }
    }
```

The reason use `try catch` , if anybody try to add add with same HESAP (int) value for the MUSTERI i want show an error message and don't add the table.

But when i try to add same MUSTERI (also same HESAP) adding same MUSTERI with HESAP=0 value.

[image]

How can i prevent this situation? I select HESAP column is Primary KEY, but still add same MUSTERI.

Comment: Did you verify that Label1.Text gets a non-zero value when an item is selected from the dropdown list? Did you do that before adding as well? You could simply make Label1.Text visible temporarily to see whether that is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. HESAP is the primary key. However, does MUSTERI also have a Unique constraint which prevents someone from entering two MUSTERI values? That would at least prevent the data from getting into the database. So something like:

   `Alter Table AVUKAT Add Constraint UC_AVUKAT Unique ( MUSTERI )`
2. Is there a CHECK constraint on HESAP which requires that the value be greater than zero? So something like:

   `Alter Table AVUKAT Add Constraint CK_AVUKAT_HESAP Check ( HESAP > 0 )`

   It should be noted that MySQL will ignore Check constraints. Thus, you would need to enforce this rule in a Trigger. However, many database systems such as SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, Informix and others will enforce check constraints.
3. I would make the following revisions

   - I would alter the query to check for whether the value exists.
   - I would incorporate the `using` statement to ensure that my objects were disposed.
   - I would use `ExecuteNonQuery` and use the number of rows returned to determine if query did not insert anything rather than implementing a global catch-all. Unless you know exactly which error you expect, you should not use `Catch ( Exception )` to catch any exception no matter the type.

```
protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServerCstr"].ConnectionString;

    using( SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString) )
    {
        myConnection.Open();

        string hesap = Label1.Text;
        string musteriadi = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
        string avukat = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value;
        string sql = @"INSERT INTO AVUKAT( MUSTERI, AVUKAT, HESAP)
                                Select @MUSTERI, @AVUKAT, @HESAP
                                From ( Select 1 As Value ) As Z
                                Where Not Exists    (
                                                    Select 1
                                                    From AVUKAT As T1
                                                    Where T1.HESAP = @HESAP
                                                    )";

        using ( SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection) )
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HESAP", hesap);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MUSTERI", musteriadi);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AVUKAT", avukat);
            cmd.Connection = myConnection;

            int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if ( rowsAffected = 0 )
                // tell user that ID exists and their data couldn't be inserted.

            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

> > When you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth.

If the HESAP value being inserted is zero, then Label1.Text must contain a zero when the Add_Click event is fired. Looking at your DropDown event handler, there are a couple of items of note.

1. If HESAP is supposed to be an integer, you should verify that it is an integer using `int.TryParse`.
2. The query should be parameterized. Even the contents of a DropDownList should be considred user input.
3. As before, it is best to incorporate the `using` construct.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int avukat;
    int hesapNo;
    bool enabled = int.TryParse( DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value, out hesapNo ) 
        && int.TryParse( DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value, out avukat ) 
        && hesapNo != 0 
        && avukat != 0;

    if ( enabled )
    {
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServerCstr"].ConnectionString;

        using( SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString) )
        {
            myConnection.Open();

            string query = @"Select A.HESAP_NO 
                             From YAZ..MARDATA.S_TEKLIF A 
                             Where A.MUS_K_ISIM = @HesapNo"

            using( SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection) )
            {
                cmd.AddParameterWithValue( "@HesapNo", hesapNo );
                Label1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    Add.Enabled = enabled;
    Label1.Visible = false;
}
```

If you add the CHECK constraint I mentioned at the top, then the code will error on insert and the bad row will not get into the database. That should lead you back to the DataSource for DropDownList1. It would appear that its SelectedValue is being returned as zero. That would imply that source that populates DropDownList1 is pushing a value with zero in it. What is the source that populates DropDownList1?

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing too obvious here that explains the behaviour you're seeing. The most likely problem really is that the value of `Label1.Text` is `0` before the insert is executed, maybe set somewhere else in the ASP.NET page lifecycle. To make sure add a line of code after `hesap` is initialised in `Add_Click` like...

```
Response.Write("<strong>hesap == " + hesap + "</strong>");
```

...and comment out the `Response.Redirect` so you can see the output.

There are also some improvements you can make to the code to make problems less likely to occur.

It's really important that you sanitise the input to **avoid SQL injection**. Hopefully you're already doing this elsewhere that's not shown in your code snippet. If you don't know what this is then there's [heaps of questions about it](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-injection/faq) here on SO.

Also, you're not doing a query for the purpose of retrieving any rows, so **use `ExecuteNonQuery`**. So I'd also replace this line...

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

...with...

```
int numberOfRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Then check the value of `ExecuteNonQuery` to ensure `numberOfRows` == 1 so you know something actually happened.

You should also wrap your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` initialisers with **`using` statements**. This means that they will automatically be disposed even if something goes wrong. This will prevent memory issues and problems with connections being left open.

Finally, **let the exception value flow through** into the `catch` statement by changing that line to `catch (Exception ex)`. Output the exception using `ex.ToString()` to see all of its details. Right now you don't know what might have gone wrong if an exception occurs.

Comment: you are right. But Label1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
 i calculate one value. I don't care executenonquery() how many rows affected. I still don't understand why i have to use Executenonquery()..

Comment: @Soner: Here's a few reasons: 1. Number of rows tells you if the stored proc behaved as you expected. 2. The SqlDataReader is using unnecessary resources. 3. It's confusing to a person reading the code when `ExecuteReader` is used but nothing is actually read. You don't "have to" use `ExecuteNonQuery` as I think this line of your code will still work, but using the correct method makes the code more robust, readable, and use less resources. Hope this helps.

Comment: I see. There is a question for you. How can i measure 'SqlDataReader' or other method using resources?? Is there any way doing this in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to insert a sample data directly to your database and try to test adding same MUSTERI and HESAP to the table. You should get an error.

And i think you should modify your query for inserting data at `Add_Click`

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AVUKAT VALUES (@MUSTERI, @AVUKAT, @HESAP)", myConnection);
```

it should be:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AVUKAT (MUSTERI, AVUKAT, HESAP) VALUES (@MUSTERI, @AVUKAT, @HESAP)", myConnection);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this not help. These are same queries by the way.

Comment: I think you should use cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: They won't get an error so long as the target table has three fields in the correct ordinal positions.  That said, I think there is something to be said for explicitly stating one's intention for what values are going to what fields...

Answer (score 1):

Hi soner
To insert record in database we have call cmd.executenonreader() methods
I think that is problem please chek it & let me know.

Comment: With ExecuteScalar(), i'm getting one value HESAP number, i think this isn't wrong, right?

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at your database schema, it's difficult to make any kind of real guess about what's going on here, but I might propose the following.

Does your database have unique indexes set up for the two values that you don't want to duplicate?

Is your database table set up so that primary keys are auto-generated, or are you manually managing primary keys?

Are any triggers causing the issue?

Are you certain that the code responsible for displaying the primary key column is retrieving it correctly in all scenarios?

Has the insert actually occurred? If the insert hasn't occurred, you're seeing the default value for integral values, which would be zero.

Comment: like i said I have a table name AVUKAT and it's columns (AVUKAT, HESAP(Primary KEY), MUSTERI) and other table but it doesn't matter. I managing manually my primary key and i don't use trigger.

Answer (score 1):

If error is in add button event, then the evil is `Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());` swap the `connection.close()` and `response.redirect`. because after page redirection the myconnection object is lost.

That should be this manner

```
 myconnection.close();
   Response.redirect("url",false);
```

i think it will work..

Comment: you are righr but that doesn't solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

My next step would be to fire up profiler and find out what your application is ACTUALLY sending to SQL Server.  Make sure the values coming in are what you expect them to be, then execute the query directly in SSMS/QA to make sure it behaves as expected.

I'm with Alex in that the culprit is *probably* an unexpected value in your label.  Find out for sure what SQL Server is seeing so you know which value needs more attention throughout the page life cycle.

Comment: This isn't about SQL Server or my query.

Answer (score 1):

While trying to add the duplicate record, are you selecting value in both the drop-downs? I can make a wild guess that your second drop-down  for AVUKAT is not selected and hence your `Label1.Text` is set to null resulting in 0 being inserted for primary key.

Comment: i calculate automaticly background HESAP value (primary key). But when i put try-catch there is no solution for error and adding HESAP (calculate with AVUKAT) with 0.